# Not able to pass arguments in shell_exec function

Tags: php, mingw, shell-exec

I am pretty new to using the shell commands.I am doing a debugger application in php.I need to check the result of the .exe files to check whether the logic of the code is right.So I tried a test program .

The C program is

## include

```
#define MAX 128
int main(char c)
{
const int max=127;
char array[max]; // char array[10];
char string[MAX];
scanf("%c",&c);
array[0] = string[0] = c;
printf("%c %c\n", array[0], string[0]);
return 0;
}
```

This is compiled as se.exe

PHP CODE

```
<?php 
define('STDIN',fopen("php://stdin","r"));
$cor1=1;
$op=shell_exec("se.exe H");
echo($op);  
if($op=="H H")
$cor1+=1;
echo $cor1;
if($cor1>1)
{echo "PASSED";}
else
{echo "FAILED";}
?>
```

This is not echoing any values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the argument is successfully being passed. The c code not using the argument. It is doing `scanf` to get user input and not really using the argument that is being passed. You need to change the c code to use the argument.

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) { 
    /* ... 
    argv[0] will have the executable name as a char array (char *)
    argv[1] will have the first command line argument as a char array (char *)
    argv[1][0] will have the first character of the first parameter that you seem to be interested.
    ensure that you do proper null check or you will get core dump/application crash
    */ 
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the response.I tried using command line arguments and even tried executing them in the command prompt using arguments.It did not work out as well.

Comment: #include<stdio.h>
    #include<stdlib.h>
    int main(int argc,char *argv) {
    int rad=argv[1];
    printf("%c ", rad);
    return 1;
    } @Code Warrior

Comment: the above code when executed from command prompt or php exec function prints the same output,irrespective of what the argument is. The output returned is  /   .just this slash .

Comment: sorry i forgot the square brackets.It is working fine now!

Answer (score 0):

The c program is printing a new line \n in the below line

```
printf("%c %c\n", array[0], string[0]);
```

In the php code, the comparison string is not including newline in the below line

```
if($op=="H H")
```

I suggest you change the php code to compare including newline (use strcmp to compare strings. Don't use == operator to compare strings)

```
if(strcmp($op, "H H\n") == 0)
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: thanks for the response.I removed the \n from the C program and also used strcmp. But the result does not change.

Comment: not just this program.I tried a few others too. The argument does not get inside the program.I tried the area of a circle program.The output was always 0.000000 . @Code Warrior

Comment: Can you copy & paste the result of your run/execution?